# Check if list contains specific string

Tags: string, bash, list, if-statement, comparison

I have a two variables (`PACKAGE_NAME` and `PACKAGE_LIST`) and I am trying to check if `PACKAGE_LIST` contains `PACKAGE_NAME`.

Here is what I have:

```
PACKAGE_LIST="rpm-foo-bar:5.0.1"
PACKAGE_NAME="rpm-foo"

if [[ ${PACKAGE_LIST} =~ "${PACKAGE_NAME}" ]]; then
  echo "PACKAGE_NAME is in PACKAGE_LIST"
else
  echo "PACKAGE_NAME is NOT in PACKAGE_LIST"
fi
```

The problem I'm having is that while `rpm-foo` is similar to `rpm-foo-bar`, it is not the same and should fall into the else statement (`PACKAGE_NAME` is NOT in `PACKAGE_LIST`). I've tried adding a `$` to the string comparison, however this only works if `PACKAGE_LIST` ends in the `PACKAGE_NAME`. Instead, `PACKAGE_LIST` has a version appended to it. How can I make make this check smarter so that the check falls into "`PACKAGE_NAME` is NOT in `PACKAGE_LIST`"?

NOTE: sometimes `PACKAGE_LIST` will not contain a version and will look like:

```
PACKAGE_LIST="rpm-foo-bar"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
[[ ${PACKAGE_LIST} =~ "${PACKAGE_NAME}:" || ${PACKAGE_LIST} == ${PACKAGE_NAME} ]]
```

Comment: That works when PACKAGE_LIST contains the version. I've update the question to include that it doesn't always look like that.

Comment: I hadn't thought about using an or. This works great. Thanks!